# Multithreaded access to data structure

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, list, pthreads

I am writing application in Linux using C, pthreads and sockets.

This will be client-server application, server will have N+2 threads, where N - number of active clients, one thread for accepting new connections and creating threads for clients and last one will be accepting user input.

I will be using linked list to save some data that will be relevant to my application, with every client there will be associated one node in my list. Those client threads will update information that is stored in their nodes with some interval, could be one second, could be two minutes, it will dynamically change.

Now here is the problem, if user requests it, the information stored in linked list needs to be written to standard output. Of course during writing I should acquire mutex. I am worried that one mutex for whole list will hinder the performance.

I was thinking about associating mutex with every node, but it will complicate removal of some specified node (firstly, I would need to make sure that the 'stdout writer' thread won't be traversing the list, I would also need to acquire mutex of my node and the previous one to change the pointer that points to the next node and so on - either I would need to traverse all the way to the previous or I would need to make double linked list).

So I am wondering if the solution that involves multiple mutexes is even better with much more complicated code, conditions and all of this locking, waiting and unlocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that having a per-node mutex will make code more complex. That's a tradeoff you will have to decide the value of. You can either have a single lock for the entire list, that might cause lock contention, but the code is largely not impacted by the presence of the lock and thus easier to write, or you can have more locks with considerably less opportunity for contention, leading to better performance, but the code is harder to write and get correct. You could even have something in the middle by having a lock per group of nodes - allocate a few nodes together and have a lock for that group - but then you'll have issues with tracking a free list and the potential for fragmentation.

You'll need to consider the relative frequency of add operations, delete operations, and full-list iterations, as well as others (reorganization, searching, whatever else your application will require). If add/delete are extremely frequent, but walking the list is once every third blue moon, the single lock could easily be appropriate. But if walking the list (whether for a full dump of the data, or to search or something else) is very common, the more granular approach becomes more attractive. You might even need to consider reader/writer locks instead of mutexes.

Comment: And what about this, instead of physically removing nodes I would marked them as 'unused', this way during the writing of the data and removal there won't be any problem because I won't need to access any other nodes, if the reader wants to traverse the list he would lock it, also list addition would only occur if the list is not being traversed by the reader.

Comment: You could do that as well - but consider whether it's worth it. Adding a new node would become searching for an unused node and then allocating one if there are no unused nodes. Traversing the list would have to be smart enough to skip over unused ones. Deleting would be somewhat easier, as you wouldn't have to adjust links, but you would still need to use a lock just to mark the node unused, so you might as well pull it out of the list anyway. All around, I think marking nodes as unused makes the code more complicated for not much gain.

Comment: Ok, I think I will use read-writer locks, as far as I understand I can guarantee that writer will have permission over reader to access the list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to traverse the list all the way back: while you traverse it, you test if the next element is the one that you want to remove, and then you may lock both nodes - always in the same order throughout the code, so you avoid deadlocking. Also, you can use the *double checking idiom* and lock the mutex node when you need to be sure of what it has.

```
remove
    for node in list
        if node->next is the desired node
            lock(node)
            lock(node->next)
                if node->next is the desired node
                    do removing stuff
                else
                    treat concurrent modification - retry, maybe?
            release(node->next)
            release(node)
```

With this idiom you don't need to lock the entire list while reading it, and also checks for a modification performed between the first test and the locking. I don't believe the code would get that much more complicated with an array of mutexes, and the locking overhead is nothing compared with the operations you may do, as IO.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have tens or even hundreds of thousands of users, it won't take that long to read the list.  You might want to create a local, intermediate list so the original is not locked while writing, which *might* take some time.  This also means you get a snapshot of the list at one point in time.  If you lock individual nodes, you could remove A, *then* remove element B, and yet have A appear in the displayed list when B does not.

As I understand it, if you *do* want to lock individual nodes, your list must be singly linked.  Additions and removals get rather tricky.  In Java, there are several system classes that do this using fast compare-and-swap techniques.  There must be code like it in C, but I don't know where to look for it.  And you will get those chronologically-challenged results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have N thread for N active client then think about the option of using pthread_setspecific and pthread_getspecific.

Comment: It would work, but there is this problem that I would neet do retrieve data in other thread, user input thread would print data to stdout and if this would be thread specific I don't think I can get the results from every thread in one thread.

Comment: In that case, pthread_setspecific won't work. You need to lock and unlock the head of list before you are going to write something in the list node; I would rather suggest you to have tree implementation than list implementation; as tree implementation traversal will improve the performance of the system.